# Integrate scripts into delphi

Tags: delphi

How can I execute an external script in Delphi (like wsh, vbs, bat...) and get back the result? I want to launch them as task within a thread do other things and when the result is ready the scripts itself will inform the application which will receive it in main thread. How to achieve that?

Comment: How do you want to receive the response from the script? Do you want to get hold of stdout?

Answer (score 7):

Use Microsoft's [Windows Script COM interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589.aspx), in particular the `IActiveScript` interface.

Comment: Apparently the link to Scalabium.com provides a reasonable Delphi componentized wrapper to these interfaces.

Comment: the link provided has gone dead... more MSDN shenanigans! (:-D) The new link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You mention a lot of different script languages and engines in your question. They have all different possibilities. If you are free to choose your script language i would suggest two approaches:

1. Have a look at http://www.scalabium.com/smscript.htm they have a nice component to execute a script (VBScript, JavaScipt) and get the return value.
2. Have a look at http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx RemObjects Pascal Script, this is a very powerfull script language and there are plenty of examples around.

Comment: +1 for your first link there, appears to be what the OP wants.

Comment: I am not sure if I can run such script: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscrip /wmi_disks.htm#Example_1__VBScript_to_Display_Logical_Disk_Information

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [Delphi Web Script (DWS).](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dws/) This is excellent and aggressively updated by Eric - see [his blog](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/f/81085?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20delphifeeds%20%28DelphiFeeds.com%29).

Comment: Does this execute wsh, vbs, bat etc.?

Comment: No, DWS only executes its own dialect of Delphi/Pascal.

Comment: So it doesn't really sound like it's what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Fast Report have Fast Script used in their famous reporting Fast Report

TMS software also have [TMS Scriptor studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudio.asp?s=#import) and [TMS Scriptor studio pro](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudiopro.asp)